# Neo4j: Change the default ID data type from integer to GUID

Tags: neo4j

I'm using Neo4j version 5.6 and want to change the default node ID type from integer to GUID.

I found a post that said to open neo4j.conf and edit the dbms.id.type setting. However, I have searched this file and there's no such setting.

How can I change the node default ID data type to GUID?

Thanks

Comment: Please put a link to the post in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two `id` functions in `Neo4j`. One is [`id()`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id) which is deprecated in Neo4j 5.0 and above. This function returns an `integer id`.

The second one is [`elementId`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-elementid) new in version 5.0 and above, and it returns a `string`. However, both of these `id's` are reused by Neo4j when nodes and relationships are deleted. So, it's not advised to use them in your query.

So, if you want to `GUID` as node ids, create a new node property and store it in them. Also, there is no such setting named `dbms.id.type` in the configurations. You can find the list of all available settings [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/reference/configuration-settings/).

You can use [`randomUUID`](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-randomuuid) function to generate a `GUID` or `apoc.uuid.install` as suggested by @fbiville in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to customize the ID (or element ID) type since those have a very internal role.

An alternative is to automatically generate GUID e.g. for new nodes.
APOC offers this: [apoc.uuid.install](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.1/graph-updates/uuid/#automatic-uuids).